# Connect object and variabile $object-> $variabile [ PHP ]

Tags: php

I try to make query to database, base on user input, because I have multiple inputs in single form it's a big more complicated.

I decide to check if input is filled like:

```
$query = "";
if((trim($searchParams->firstname)))
    $query .= "firstname,";
```

which works correctly for me, and after I check each input I explode string to array by `,` and foreach it

```
$querys = explode(",", $query);
foreach($querys as $q)
{
 ...
}
```

What basically create an array of all filled inputs, however just their names base on what i need to get values as well. 
So I try to add something like this to query

```
$searchParams->$q;
```

But this doesn't work (say it's empty despite the fact if i echo it before it's filled)

I try to do something really dirt as:

```
    $param = "$searchParams->".$q;
    $values .= $param;
```

which say

> Object of class could not be converted to string ( if i var_dump($q) it say its string so i dont understand)

I think I 'm doing it really badly but thats the only thing I found out as potentially useful. Any advise to fix this will be helpful.

p.s. Here is how final query should looks like:

```
"SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE firstname = ? AND surname = ?" ,$searchParams->firstname, $searchParams->surname
```

Comment: Can you dump $param?

Comment: Hi @MHakvoort if i dump $param which is $param = "$searchParams->".$q; it says object of class  could not be converted to string
 <br>
If i dump $q it say name of each input what is correctly

Comment: $searchParams is a object class which cannot be converted to string as far as your error is concerned

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Undefined_variable , this make sense but it should be able to access it from $object ->$variabile

Comment: It says that when you do var_dump($param); ?